# configure: error: working directory cannot be determined

Tags: php, centos, centos7

This is 10000x more easy on Ubuntu or Debian, but my partner who is supposed to be accustomed with CentOS absolutely wanted to use CentOS, but he didn't even know how to install PHP. So I have to do all myself.

We want to install an apache2 server with PHP, PHP-SSH2, PHP-MYSQL, PHP-GD and PHP-CURL.

So I've been trying to install PHP SSH2 on the dedicated server, but I get this error:

```
downloading ssh2-0.13.tgz ...
Starting to download ssh2-0.13.tgz (28,984 bytes)
.........done: 28,984 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
libssh2 prefix? [autodetect] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootgdfvCp/ssh2-0.13
running: /var/tmp/ssh2/configure --with-ssh2
configure: error: working directory cannot be determined
ERROR: `/var/tmp/ssh2/configure --with-ssh2' failed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `yum install libssh2`

Comment: I've already done that, but still not working.

Comment: ? May be `libssh2-devel`

Comment: Already installed that, but still not working.

Comment: What does PHP SSH2 do? Can you use the userspace phpseclib instead?

Comment: After 3 days loose just to install php ssh2, I decided to reinstall the server on Ubuntu 20.04.